# Ocupar todo el ancho y alto de la pantalla con un QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, layout, qtablewidget

Estoy tratando de ocupar todo el ancho y alto de mi ventana con un QTable Widget para ello tengo:

```
#Mi layout
vboxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)   
self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
vboxLayout.addLayout(self.mainLayout)
vboxLayout.addStretch() 

#Tabla
self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
self.table.setObjectName("table")    
self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")    

#Layout
self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 6, 0, 5, 7)
```

Y lo que se ve por pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿QTableView o QTableWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que el QTableWidget se expanda por toda la ventana y este dentro del QGridLayout no debes usar addStretch(), ademas de indicar la fila, columna, rowSpan y columnSpan:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Mi layout
        vboxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)   
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        vboxLayout.addLayout(self.mainLayout)

        #Tabla
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")    

        #Layout
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```